# How can I access variable values in a SWF on a running webpage?

Tags: python, flash

I've been using a combination of [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org) and Python to create a very low-level script that automates playing various levels of a [Flash game](http://www.kongregate.com/games/xdanond/rpg-shooter-starwish), but I can only do so much through visual image recognition. What I want to do is be able to **access variables within the *running* flash game**, as opposed to accessing static data via downloading and extracting, etc. By variables I mean info such as player position, experience earned, etc. Methods such as ExternalInterface won't work since that requires modification on the server end, as opposed to my client end. I'll use any programming language, etc. that makes this possible, but... *is* it possible?

**TL;DR:**
Is it possible to find the values of variables within an actively running SWF as they are updated, without any help server-side?

***EDIT:*** Can I create a "wrapper" swf to load the external server-based swf and then subsequently access the information in the variables within that swf and pass them on to me?

Comment: See If you can modify StoryText to work with swf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975211/how-does-the-gui-testing-tool-pyusecase-compare-to-dogtail

Answer (score 2):

Without the source of the swf you can't. You can decompile the swf and modify the code to provide you with the data.

Comment: Would there be any way that I could use a self-created swf (ie. self.swf) to load the [Flash game](http://www.kongregate.com/games/xdanond/rpg-shooter-starwish) (ie. ext.swf) within self.swf, which would then access the data within ext.swf and make it accessible?

Comment: No loading only lets you play the file from within your file and does not expose the guts of the file to you.